# How can I make my admin page (for removing users from DB) not display other users in the list if they have an admin role?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am making an admin page that lists all current users in the database of my web application. I am trying to make it so that users with the role admin, do not appear in the list, essentially preventing admins from removing other admins. How can I accomplish this? This is my code:

BoardAdmin.jsx:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import UserService from '../../services/user.service';
import './styles/BoardAdmin.css';
const BoardAdmin = () => {
    const [content, setContent] = useState('');
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        UserService.getAdminBoard().then(
            (response) => {
                setUsers(response.data);
                // console.log(response.data);
            },
            (error) => {
                const _content =
                    (error.response &&
                        error.response.data &&
                        error.response.data.message) ||
                    error.message ||
                    error.toString();
                setContent(_content);
            }
        );
    }, []);
    return (
        <div className='page'>
            <header className='jumbotron'>
                <div className='column-names'>
                    <p className='user-id-column'>User ID</p>
                    <p className='username-column'>Username</p>
                    {/* <p>User Role</p> */}
                    <p className='user-email-column'>Email</p>
                </div>
                {users.map((user) => (
                    <ul className='user-list'>
                        <li class='user'>
                            <div>
                                <div class='info'>
                                    <span class='user-id'>{user.id}</span>
                                    <span class='name'>{user.username}</span>
                                    <span class='role'>{user.role}</span>
                                    <span class='email'>{user.email}</span>
                                    <img class='remove' src='https://i.imgur.com/CemzWSg.png' />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class='expand'></div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                ))}
            </header>
        </div>
    );
};
export default BoardAdmin;
```

I can access the users role if I check the state with an auth file of mine with  `const { user: currentUser } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);` and  `if (currentUser) { setShowAdminBoard(currentUser.roles.includes("ROLE_ADMIN"));`. Can anyone help me figure out how I can accomplish this? Does it need to be done on the backend? Any help would be appreciated, and I will include more code if it is necessary.

Comment: Are you saying that `response.data` returned from `UserService.getAdminBoard()` has the users with possibly an admin role that you want to filter out?

Comment: This needs to be done on the backend for security purposes. There is no need to handle this in the frontend even if you could.

Comment: @DrewReese Yes, the `response.data` from `UserService.getAdminBoard()` has users with an admin role that I would like filtered out. Apparently from others responses (thank you guys I appreciate the help), this should be handled in the backend though for security purposes. What do you think?

Comment: Thanks. My suggestion was going to be similar to GMaiolo's answer. I can provide it if you like, but yes, ideally you don't want to transmit data the frontend isn't interested in. It wastes network resources and backend machines tend to be more powerful/faster than front end devices.

Comment: @DrewReese I ended up implementing this on the backend after some headaches haha, thank you again Drew.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to filter out users with that role when rendering them in your JSX.

```
// Assuming that "ROLE_ADMIN" is the unwanted role
{users.filter(user => user.role !== "ROLE_ADMIN").map((user) => (
  <ul className='user-list'>
    <li class='user'>
      ...
```

**Security note:** it is recommended to handle this on the backend of your application, as anything performed on the client can be manipulated.

Comment: `Does it need to be done on the backend?`

OP specifically asked this so I think you should rather be suggesting him to do this in the backend due to possible security issues.

Comment: @RubekJoshi It does not need to be done on the backend (although I agree it would be recommended for security purposes) and also there is no backend code to suggest a solution either. Most of the question is related to a display issue. I'll edit the answer adding the recommendation though.

Comment: Thank you both for the help. Im gonna look into what I need to do for the backend to filter it out from there. This solution here looks useful, but if im handling that in the backend, would this be necessary for the frontend still?

Comment: @StephenAranda it shouldn't be necessary as the data wouldn't be there.